# Parent child relationship confusion with reference semantics (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I was just doing some experiments with inheritance in swift, and this is my code:

```
class parent {
    var value: Int?
}

class child1: parent {

    func setParent() {
        value? = 213
    }
}

class child2: parent {

    func setParent(){
        value? = 234
    }
}

let a = child1()
let b = child2()

a.setParent()

print(b.value) //nil
print(a.value) //nil
```

I have setup a `parent` class which only has a value property, and I have a `child1` and `child2` which inherits from `parent`.

Under the reference semantics, if I set the `value` property to a value (213), if I go to check the value under `child2`, I should see the same value because `child1` and `child2` both inherits from `parent`, pointing towards the `parent` class. But it turns out that if I print the values, both are nil...can someone explain this?

Thanks!

Comment: Completely unrelated, I'd suggest following standard naming conventions, where classes `Child1`, `Child2` and `Parent` should begin with uppercase letters. It makes your code less confusing. Variables and methods should start with lowercase letters, but classes, structs, protocols, etc. should start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
value? = 213
```

and

```
value? = 234
```

Those say "if it's not `nil`, set the value to 213 (or 234, respectively)". That's obviously not what you mean.

You should remove those `?` when you assign those values. I.e., those should be, respectively:

```
value = 213
```

and

```
value = 234
```

---

Once we fixed that, you followed up with:

> Shouldn't we expect `b.value` also yield the value `213`?"

No. The `a` is an instance of `child1` with an instance property `value`, which it inherits from superclass `parent`. The `b` is a completely separate instance, a `child2` which inherits its own instance variable, `value`, from  superclass `parent`. Just because `child1` and `child2` inherit from `parent` doesn't change the fact that `value` is an instance property, and thus separate instances `a` and `b` will get their own unique instances of `value`.

Comment: how come? the value inside `parent` is an optional? also, I tried your approach and it worked. But shouldn't we expect `b.value` also yield the value `213`?

Comment: "how come" ... It's effectively optional chaining. E.g. `object?.someMethod()` will only call `someMethod` if `object` is not `nil`. The same is true with `=`. Doing `value? = ...` will only do `=` if `value` is not `nil`.

Comment: "shouldn't we expect `b.value` also yield the value `213`?" ... no, see expanded answer above.